# excel vba followhyperlink method when no workbook is open

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I created a custom UI in excel 2007 as a part of xlam add-in.
The custom tab includes a button that opens a website when clicked.

I used `ThisWorkbook.followHyperlink "address"`

The add-in is password protected which causes excel to crash whenever i click on the button while in xlam add-in.
Everything works fine when I use it in an .xlsm  file.

I think the problem is in the `ThisWorkbook` being password protected. I could use `ActiveWorkbook` instead but the app would crash when there is no workbook open.

Any suggestions how I could work around this? (Unprotecting the file is not an option)

Comment: Do you have any error handling code around?? That would help if you switch from `ThisWorkbook` into `ActiveWorkbook` according to what you said. You could show part of your code to get additional information...

Comment: That's all the code there is in the UI call back function. It is just meant to go to a website when button is clicked. Excel just crashes I don't have any error code or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including information from comment + assumption that this need to work only when any activeworkbook is open... than you could try to change from `Thisworkbook` into `Activeworkbook` in the way like this:

```
Sub FollowingHyperlink()

   'check if there is anything open
If Not ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
Else
    'if not... it depends what you have and what you need
    'you could just open any new workbook
    '**This part of code edited**
    'or use this technique to navigate to page using IE:
    Dim ieAPP
    Set ieAPP = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ieAPP.Visible = True
    ieAPP.navigate "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I decided to open a new workbook in the else section but I am not really satisfied with that solution. Is there a way to open webpage that does not require a workbook object? Do you know why it requires workbook object at all?